# how get key/value from nsuserdefaults .plist configuration file Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, airwatch, mobileiron

I am working as a Xamarin forms iOS enterprise app. 
We pushed config.plist (Some key-value pair) file to a real device using Mobileiron/airwatch MDM/EMM(Services). Then we deploy the Apps on iPads using MobileIron. When the app starts, the app gets Url/ credentials from config.plist that pushed by MDM.

after googling I found config.plist stored in device which in NSUserDefaults​

But I am don't know is the .plist stored in NSUserDefaults with apps bundle id or something else.

Please anybody has the same issue before writing to me how I have to implements or getting value from .plist

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find the details from your question on page 69-70 of Apple's [MDM-Protocol-Reference](https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/MDM-Protocol-Reference.pdf). The MDM server deploys these settings using a dictionary that contains an array of bundle ids, with the settings for each app within their key. Because of how sandboxing works, your app just has to retrieve the `com.apple.configuration.managed` key to get its settings.

A great resource is https://www.appconfig.org/ios/